# Read csv file with columns names as rows and edit date time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a huge data file which looks like this. I have shown only a few parameters in the column 'Name'. I have 24 of them which keep repeating.

```
    Name    Value      Date            Time
0   FAN_RFB   1      2018-04-07      02:34:43
1   KW_TOTAL  186    2018-04-08      23:59:58
2   ME_POW_1  8618   2018-04-08      23:59:56
3   ME_POW_2  8315   2018-04-08      23:59:56
4   FAN_RFB   1      2018-04-07      02:34:43
5   KW_TOTAL  185    2018-04-09      00:00:07
6   ME_POW_1  8467   2018-04-09      00:00:09
7   ME_POW_2  8350   2018-04-09      00:00:09
8   FAN_RFB   1      2018-04-07      02:34:43
9   KW_TOTAL  182    2018-04-09      00:00:15
10  ME_POW_1  8783   2018-04-09      00:00:16
11  ME_POW_2  8422   2018-04-09      00:00:16
12  FAN_RFB   1      2018-04-07      02:34:43
13  KW_TOTAL  184    2018-04-09      00:00:26
14  ME_POW_1  8545   2018-04-09      00:00:28
15  ME_POW_2  8370   2018-04-09      00:00:28
```

There are two things I want to do with this:

1. The right date and time for each set is the one recorded for ME_POW_1. So for the index 0 to 3 I want to correct the date and time of all with the data and time for ME_POW_1 and I want to do it for all of the data.
2. The names in the Column 'Name' should be pivoted to individual columns. The desired output is:

   Date          Time      FAN_RFB    KW_TOTAL  ME_POW_1   ME_POW_2
    2018-04-08  23:59:56       1         186     8618       8315
    2018-04-09  00:00:09       1         185     8467       8350
    2018-04-09  00:00:16       1         182     8783       8422
    2018-04-09  00:00:28       1         184     8545       8370

I think the second may be possible by using pd.pivot (index='date', columns='Name', values='Values'). Once I can get the dates of sets similar then I can use this piece of code to get the desired output:

```
raw=pd.read_csv('example.csv', parse_dates=True, usecols=[0,1,2,3])
raw['Date']=pd.to_datetime(raw['Date']+''+raw['Time'])
raw=raw.drop(['Time'], axis=1)
raw1=raw.pivot(index='Date', columns='Name', values='Value')
```

But I have no idea of how to accomplish the first task to change the date of each set as per the date and time of ME_POW_1. Could anyone please guide me?

Comment: These appear in a repeating order and I will assume the pattern continues. I would use a dictionary. So put the first 4 names in a list in a dictionary, then assign the time from the time column. Not sure what you are going to output this to but at least the data will be structured.

Comment: How working my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Solution  working if  repeating `pattern` for each 4 rows and each group contain `ME_POW_1` row:

---

I think you can first add parameter `parse_dates` by list of `date` and `time` column for `datetimes`:

```
df=pd.read_csv('example.csv', usecols=[0,1,2,3], parse_dates=[['Date','Time']])

print (df)
             Date_Time      Name  Value
0  2018-04-07 02:34:43   FAN_RFB      1
1  2018-04-08 23:59:58  KW_TOTAL    186
2  2018-04-08 23:59:56  ME_POW_1   8618
3  2018-04-08 23:59:56  ME_POW_2   8315
4  2018-04-07 02:34:43   FAN_RFB      1
5  2018-04-09 00:00:07  KW_TOTAL    185
6  2018-04-09 00:00:09  ME_POW_1   8467
7  2018-04-09 00:00:09  ME_POW_2   8350
8  2018-04-07 02:34:43   FAN_RFB      1
9  2018-04-09 00:00:15  KW_TOTAL    182
10 2018-04-09 00:00:16  ME_POW_1   8783
11 2018-04-09 00:00:16  ME_POW_2   8422
12 2018-04-07 02:34:43   FAN_RFB      1
13 2018-04-09 00:00:26  KW_TOTAL    184
14 2018-04-09 00:00:28  ME_POW_1   8545
15 2018-04-09 00:00:28  ME_POW_2   8370
```

Then get `Date_Time` by filtering `ME_POW_1` rows and create default index by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
s = df.loc[df['Name'] == 'ME_POW_1', 'Date_Time'].reset_index(drop=True)
print (s)
0   2018-04-08 23:59:56
1   2018-04-09 00:00:09
2   2018-04-09 00:00:16
3   2018-04-09 00:00:28
Name: Date_Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Last pivot for each `4` rows and last [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) new column for first position:

```
df = pd.pivot(index=df.index // 4, columns=df['Name'], values=df['Value'])

df.insert(0, 'Date', s)
print (df)
Name                Date  FAN_RFB  KW_TOTAL  ME_POW_1  ME_POW_2
0    2018-04-08 23:59:56        1       186      8618      8315
1    2018-04-09 00:00:09        1       185      8467      8350
2    2018-04-09 00:00:16        1       182      8783      8422
3    2018-04-09 00:00:28        1       184      8545      8370
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It is working for a repeating pattern. As of now the data I have repeats after every 24 rows. If it changes I will try to find a way. Thanks again :)

Comment: @ArunKrishnan - sso change `//4` to `//24` only :)

Comment: Yes. I did that. But in case I get data where the pattern is not repeating it will be challenging. Will look into it then. Thanks again :)